# HTTP status code - function called mapping

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I'm starting learning **ajax-jquery**

How does **jquery** decide whether the request is successful or not?
(**success** being called vs **error** being called)

I mean , I think it should have something to do with the **HTTP status code** received by the
server,but is there anywhere a mapping between status codes and the function called?

HTTP status code == 200   -> success

HTTP status code !=200 -> error

Is this guess right ?
But It doesn't make sense to calle error also on redirections.

Answer (score 1):

Code failure is not linked to a single HTTP status code, as there are multiple possible status codes that lead to errors. I could be wrong on this part, but I think that, if the readyState never changes to 4, an `abort` gets thrown and calls `error` without returning an HTTP status call at all.

I found a useful resource on HTTP status codes and AJAX [here.](http://www.j2mesalsa.com/ajax/properties.php)